# Data Sync between local and Server DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm using Ado.Net Data Entity Model to add records to a local Sql Compact database every second. I want to sync it to a database on the server.
Can you point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

do you have to write to both databases? how about setting up a replication between the databases?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753) was designed for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Sync framework in  our projects . we have implemented sync in sql server and PG SQL ,  It works reasonably well for us . In addition we have implemented batching too.

To start with refer this documentation and sample code

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4835

This will show you how to synchronize data between multiple sql server databases. You can also customize the 'increments' stored procedures to take custom parameters and filter data based on these parameters (for instance people the client-user is planning to visit).

I will also suggest that you use a reflector to decompile Sync framework code in case you see wierd errors - sometimes it is not possible to figure out where the error is till you see the exception getting caught in the framework code. Redgate works perfectly for me!

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: refer to this document also http://www.infoq.com/articles/Microsoft-Sync-Framework-PostgreSql;jsessionid=398CB169CBCEA527DB7E96E47B40F1C9     which actually speaks about pg sql sync but other than the difference in providers the procedure to be followed is same .